# long for 12 digit number?

Tags: c++, types, long-integer, digit

I'm trying to use `long` for 12 digit number but it's saying "integer constant is too large for "long" type", and I tried it with C++ and Processing (similar to Java).  What's happening and what should I use for it?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample so that we can see specific details?

Comment: @Blindy, Sorry, I thought it might be useful.  Obviously it is unnecessary though.

Comment: will you be using this number for calculations? It's strange that you asking for a "12 digit number". Normally people are interested in a range and they specify if it is signed or not. If you are just dealing with a number like a credit card number or some phone number then it would be better to store as a string.

Comment: I didn't think it was strange.  But then, I've had to write code to interoperate with COBOL.

Comment: well the number is 600851475143 and I have to find out the largest prime factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know in C++, but in C, there is a header file called `<stdint.h>` that will portably have the integer types with the number of bits you desire.

```
int8_t 
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
```

and their unsigned counterpart (uint8_t and etc).

Update: the header is called `<cstdint>` in C++

Comment: can you please the above comment, its quite causing a problem when i use it

Answer (score 5):

In C and C++ (unlike in Java), the size of `long` is implementation-defined.  Sometimes it's 64 bits, sometimes it's 32.  In the latter case, you only have enough room for 9 decimal digits.

To guarantee 64 bits, you can use either the `long long` type, or a fixed-width type like `int64_t`.

Comment: +1 for specific-width types, like those achievable through `cstdint` if your platform has it, or [`boost/cstdint.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/integer/cstdint.htm) if it doesn't.

Comment: Just FYI - on some compilers (e.g. older GCC), `cstdint` is missing but the platform may have C99's `stdint.h`....

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifying a literal constant, you must use the appropriate type specifier:

```
int i = 5;
unsigned i = 6U;

long int i = 12L;
unsigned long int i = 13UL;

long long int i = 143LL;
unsigned long long int i = 144ULL;

long double q = 0.33L;

wchar_t a = L'a';
```

Comment: I really think that in his case was the problem of a long int being 32bits

Comment: @hexa: You're probably right. OP didn't say which platform/compiler/settings, I'm not sure which combinations of types and literal constants would cause which sort of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `long long` in gcc or `__int64` in msvc.